# Java: getting current Day of the Week value

Tags: java, calendar, weekday

At the moment, I'm creating a java schedule app and I was wondering how to find the current day of the week while using the Calendar class to get the first day of the week.

Here is the method I'm using in a class in order to set up a week schedule

```
public static String getSunday() {
    SimpleDateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat(dayDate);
    Calendar specific = cal;
    specific.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (cal.getFirstDayOfWeek() - ??));
    return d.format(specific.getTime());
}
```

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you're trying to do here.  Your method is named 'get sunday'.  It returns a formatted date String for a Calendar that contains an unspecified starting date moved forward a number of days calculated by subtracting something from the first day of the week.  What is the starting date?  What are you attempting to return?

Comment: cal is created under the Calendar class that gets the instance. It's initialized under the constructor and what I was attempting to do was align days dates "3/11" under the appropriate day "thurs".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the current day of the week by calling `get()` with `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`

```
public int getTodaysDayOfWeek() {
  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  return c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
}
```

Also, while I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do, it looks fishy to me. (What's `cal` for example?)

Comment: Now outdated. The troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque well the answer is from 2010 :)

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

> how to find the current day of the week

```
DayOfWeek.from( LocalDate.now() )
```

> set up a week schedule

```
LocalDate sunday = 
    LocalDate.now()
             .with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ) ;

LocalDate monday = sunday.plusDays( 1 ) ;
LocalDate tuesday = monday.plusDays( 1 ) ;
…
```

## Details

The Question and other Answer both use outmoded classes.

The old date-time classes are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them.

## java.time

In Java 8 and later, we use the built-in java.time framework. Much of the functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 (ThreeTen-Backport), and further adapted to Android (ThreeTenABP).

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents the current moment in UTC with a resolution up to nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

To get the day-of-week we must determine the date. Time zone is crucial in determining the date as the date can vary around the globe for any given moment. For example, a few minutes after midnight in Paris is a new day, while in Montréal it is still “yesterday”.

Use [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to represent a time zone. Ask for a [proper time zone name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in format of `continent/region`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviations commonly seen in mainstream media as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and are not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

Use the handy [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum to determine the day of the week.

```
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from( zdt );
```

You may interrogate the `DayOfWeek` object.

You may [ask for a number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getValue--) from 1 to 7 where 1 is Monday and 7 is Sunday per the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. But do not pass this number around your code; instead pass around `DayOfWeek` objects to enjoy the benefits of type-safety and guaranteed valid values.

```
int dowNumber = dow.getValue();
```

You may want text, the name of the day of the week. Let java.time automatically translate the name into a human language. A [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) species which human language, and also specifies the cultural norms to use such as how to abbreviate and capitalize. The [`TextStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) enum indicates how long a name you want.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , locale );
```

To get the start of the week, ask for the previous Monday (or Sunday, whatever), or stick with today if it is a Monday. Use a `TemporalAdjuster` implementation found in `TemporalAdjusters` class.

```
LocalDate startOfWeek = zdt.toLocalDate().with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) );
```

If you need a date-time rather than date-only, ask java.time to get the first moment of the day (not always the time `00:00:00`).

```
ZonedDateTime zdtWeekStart = startOfWeek.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).